# How to get State Code from Region Id in Magento 2.1.9

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping, shipping-methods

I am trying to get state code form Region ID. 
e.g. If my region id = 12 state code should be CA.
This is what I am doing right now.

```
$regionObject = $objectManager->get('Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory');
$regionModel = $regionObject->create();
$region = $regionModel->loadByCode($regionId, $countryCode);
$shipFromState = $region->getName();
```

I am trying to get shipping origin address. If there is a good way to get the address that will be nice. Currently I am getting shipping information using following code

```
$scopeConfig = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface');
$regionId = $scopeConfig->getValue('shipping/origin/region_id', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    $_regionFactory- = $objectManager->get('Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory');
    $regionModel = $_regionFactory->create();

    if (is_numeric($regionId)) {
        $shipperRegion = $this->_regionFactory->create()->load($regionId);
        if($shipperRegion->getId()){
            $shipperRegionCode = $shipperRegion->getCode();
            print_r($shipperRegionCode>getData());
    }
}
```

**Note:Direct use of object manger is not good Idea**.

If you  going to ***add try this on block class,Helper,Model,ResourceModel class*** Then My suggestion is that

Inject the **factory class**  at `__construct` function then get **region data by  dependency inject**.

```
protected $_regionFactory;
protected $_scopeConfig;
public function  __construct(
  ...
  \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
  \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory $regionFactory,
  ...
) {
  $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
  $this->_regionFactory = $regionFactory;
  ...
}

public function getShippingregion()
{
      $shipperRegionId = (int) $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('shipping/origin/region_id',
          ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
          [StoreId]
      );

      if (is_numeric($shipperRegionId)) {
          $shipperRegion = $this->_regionFactory->create()->load($shipperRegionId );
          $shipperRegionCode =$shipperRegion->getCode();
      }
}
```

Comment: Whatever you have give in the second solution is what I had, but mine was not working as I was using loadByCode(). But the creat()->load() method you have shown here is working but its deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$region = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\Region')->load(12); // Region Id
print_r($region->getData());
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [region_id] => 12
    [country_id] => US
    [code] => CA
    [default_name] => California
    [name] => California
)
```

> Note: Please do not use Object Manager. Instead create function and then call it.

Comment: Is this works for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    namespace MODULENAMESPACE\MODULENAME\Helper;

    use \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory;
    use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

    class Data extends AbstractHelper {
           protected $_regionFactory;
           protected $_logger;

           public function __construct(
              RegionFactory $regionFactory,
              LoggerInterface $logger
           ){
              $this->_regionFactory = $regionFactory;
              $this->_logger = $logger;
           }

            /**
             * Gets the region data from state ID.
             * @param $state - numbers state ID
             *
             * @return array [region_id],[country_id],[code],[default_name],[name]
             */

            public function getRegionDataByName($state, $countryId = 'US') {
                try {
                    $region   = $this->_regionFactory->create();
                    $regionData = $region->loadByName($state, $countryId);
                    return $regionData;
                }
                catch(\Exception $e) {
                    $this->_logger->critical($e->getMessage());
                    return false;
                }
            }
    }
?>
```

*** Get code ***

```
call helper
<?php
    $helper = $this->dataHelper; //construct it before call
    $helper->getRegionDataByName($address->getRegion())->getCode();
?>
```